# Does CouchDB v 2.1.1 Run on WIndows 10?

Tags: windows-10, couchdb

I installed CouchDB v 2.1.1 on Windows 10 and it doesn't appear to work. I bring up Fauxton and it gives this error:

Hmmm...can’t reach this page
Make sure you’ve got the right web address: http://localhost:5984

The Apache CouchDB service was not created. 
The instructions for manually starting CouchDB indicate that you run couchdb.bat from the bin folder. There is no couchdb.bat in the bin folder.

The CouchDB installation folder is c:\couchdb.

I installed v 1.7.1_17.5 and it runs fine. The Apache CouchDB service is now installed and running.

In our application we need the _find function which is not available on v 1.7.1.

Comment: Yes CouchDB runs fine on Windows 10. You should rewrite your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CouchDB v 2.1.1 on Windows 10 64 bit, installed from couchdb-2.1.1.msi...

The Apache CouchDB service is not installed with the CouchDB installation. The couchdb.bat file in the c:\couchdb\bin folder was renamed to couchdb.cmd.

Run couchdb.cmd from a command shell with admin privilege and couchdb will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! CouchdDB 2.x works on windows 10, I've set it up myself. However, you should consider verifying if your distro is x64 because there seem not to be an official distribution for x86 windows

Comment: System type is 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor.

Comment: For CouchDB the install is couchdb-2.1.1.msi. The download web site said it was Windows (x64).

Comment: @SteveGraber Could you resolve the issue with Windows 10?

Comment: That sounds odd... It was straight forward for me to set it up with win10 x64

Comment: @user3405291 are you having similar problems?

Comment: No, I'm on Linux and I compiled CouchDB 2.1.1 from source, it went smoothly. I'm just curious why @SteveGraber has problems with CouchDB on Windows 10.

Comment: I'm on linux too, but I've had to set it up for my colleagues at work. And it was straight forward. That's what baffles me though

Comment: No I haven't resolved the issue with v 2.1.1 on Windows 10. Currently I'm using v 1.7.1 which does work on Windows 10. I'll probably have to go back to v 2.1.1 at some point...

Comment: I installed CouchDB v 1.7.1 and reinstalled couchdb-2.1.1.msi. I'm using Windows 10 64 bit. After installing v 2.1.1 there is no Apache CouchDB service and there is no couchdb.bat file in the c:\couchdb\bin folder. So... how do you start couchdb v 2.1.1 on Windows 10 64 bit?

Comment: Sorry... I meant... I UNinstalled CouchDB v 1.7.1